# Keep admin and frontend deployments in sync using Azure pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have been tripped up twice recently as our development output has increased.

We have a; backend services, an Admin SPA site and a number of frontend applications including native apps. All in different repos

We also have a fully automated CI/CD pipelines for everything that works fantastically.

What has happened recently is the public applications have gotten ahead of the Admin SPA which is making the team look bad.

Has anyone seen a solution that requires minimum input for developers - the more I can rely on automation the better.

The goal is to keep feature deployments in concert

Tanks

Comment: Perhaps setting version dependency is a good idea? Application X has its versions dependencies: {AppY: 1.1, AppZ: 2.0 ...} thus when buiding/deploying you check whether your dependencies are met. (There is no way AFAIK, in which the developers themselves wouldn't need to at least set the version dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

So the plan is to go down versioning with Semantic versioning and a route on admin that returns a json response with the version number.

The build and deploy for admin takes in the version and returns it.

The deploy for reliant apps has a script that queries admin before starting.

There is still a bit of manual work for the developers but it is manageable.

Thanks @Bruno